Cropping a Photo using cropper.js and ASP.NET - with UpdatePanel
I've been trying to solve this for about a week now.
I know it's got to be something simple.
Requirement

I need to use ASP.NET - minimal Java as the page will do most processing / DB work using ASP.NET
I need to use cropper.js to crop the image (imgImageToCrop)
Once I crop the image, I need to drop it in the original images place (imgProfilePic)
I'm using an ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender (MPE)
Needs to run in an asp:UpdatePanel (UP)
I has other UPs on the page after this component. So, I need to confine the postbacks to this UP.

Problem
It's working fine, I can upload the image, launch the ajax MPE, and set the 'cropper' info. The problem arises when I'm trying to get the original source image (the imgProfilePic) to update with the cropped image.
I've tried playing with the UP settings, storing the base64 data in a hidden field (hidImgSrc) and pulling that in after I close the MPE, all sorts of stuff, but it's eluding me & making me a bit crazy.
I 'think' it may be related to the asp:PostBackTrigger in the UP, but in order to use the asp:FileUpload inside an UP apparently, I have to use a PostBackTrigger - not an AsyncPostBackTrigger.
The code-behind for lnkbtnSaveCropped is where I'm banging my head against the wall. I've tried using Javascript with OnClientClick also code-behind that uses ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript. But at every turn the 'cropped' image flashes up in the imgProfilePic element and then the default photographer.png reappears. Hence my feeling it's a rogue post back I can't see... I've been looking at this too long.
Well, that's my dilemma, any help would be appreciated.
Here's the code - JS + CSS:
<style>
    .img-container img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    .input-group-prepend-25 {
        width: 25%; /*adjust as needed*/
    }

    .modalPopup400 {
        width: 400px;
        border: none;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    .img-icon-256 {
        width: 256px;
        height: 256px;
    }
</style>
<script>
    var cropBoxData;
    var canvasData;
    var cropper;
    var imageDataURL;

    function showFileOpen() {
        var btnFileOpen = document.getElementById('filUploadPhoto');
        btnFileOpen.click();
    }
    function getCroppedImage() {
        cropBoxData = cropper.getCropBoxData();
        canvasData = cropper.getCanvasData();
        document.getElementById("<%=imgProfilePic.ClientID %>").setAttribute('src', cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL('image/jpeg'));
    };
    function setCropper() {
        var imagetoCrop = document.getElementById('imgImageToCrop');
        cropper = new Cropper(imagetoCrop, {
            viewMode: 1,
            rounded: true,
            movable: true,
            zoomable: true,
            cropBoxResizable: false,
            cropBoxMovable: true,
            ready: function () {
                cropper.setCropBoxData(cropBoxData).setCanvasData(canvasData);
                cropper.setCropBoxData({ width: 200, height: 200 });
            }
        });
    }
</script>

ASPX markup:
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upanProfileDetails" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="False" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="row pt-2">
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upanPhotUpload" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="True" UpdateMode="Always">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <!-- Photo -->
                                <!-- ============================================================================ -->
                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-5 d-flex justify-content-center">
                                    <div class="justify-content-center pt-2">
                                        <div class="col text-center">
                                            <asp:Image ID="imgProfilePic" ImageUrl="https://i.ibb.co/hM6cBrF/photographer.png" CssClass="img-icon-256 rounded-circle img-fluid" runat="server" />
                                            <asp:FileUpload ID="filUploadPhoto" accept=".jpg, .png, .gif" runat="server" />
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnUploadImage" Text="Upload Photo" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- ============================================================================ -->
                                <!-- Modal - Crop Photo -->
                                <!-- ============================================================================ -->
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkdummyCrop" runat="server" Visible="True"></asp:LinkButton>
                                <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe_Crop"
                                    runat="server"
                                    BackgroundCssClass="modalbackground"
                                    Enabled="True"
                                    PopupControlID="panCrop"
                                    TargetControlID="lnkdummyCrop">
                                </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
                                <asp:Panel ID="panCrop" runat="server" BorderWidth="0px" CssClass="modalPopup400" Style="display: none">
                                    <div class="card">
                                        <div class="card-header bg-primary">
                                            <h1 class="modal-title fs-5 text-white">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblMsgboxTitle" runat="server" Text="Crop Image"></asp:Label>
                                            </h1>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <div class="row pb-2 pt-2">
                                                <div class="col text-center">
                                                    <div class="img-container">
                                                        <asp:Image ID="imgImageToCrop" ImageUrl="https://i.ibb.co/hM6cBrF/photographer.png" runat="server" />
                                                    </div>
                                                    <strong>Zoom In and Out - Mouse Wheel.</strong>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row text-center">
                                                <div class="col text-center">
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnCropImage" runat="server" class="btn btn-warning w-25" Text="Crop" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:LinkButton>
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnSaveCropped" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary w-25" Text="Save" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:LinkButton>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </asp:Panel>
                                <!-- ============================================================================ -->
                            </ContentTemplate>
                            <Triggers>
                                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUploadImage" />
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkbtnCropImage" EventName="Click" />
                            </Triggers>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>

                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-7">
                            <div class="row pt-1">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-text input-group-prepend-25">Name</span>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtProfileDetailsFirstName" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtProfileDetailsLastName" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row pt-1">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-text input-group-prepend-25">Phone</span>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtProfileDetailsPhone" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row pt-1">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-text input-group-prepend-25">Address
                                        </span>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtProfileDetailsAddress" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row pt-1">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-text input-group-prepend-25">Birth Year</span>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtProfileDetailsYOB" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row pt-1 d-flex justify-content-end">
                                <div class="col-9 text-start">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-3 text-end d-flex justify-content-end">
                                    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="upanProgProfileDetails" runat="server">
                                        <ProgressTemplate>
                                            <div class="pe-2">
                                                <div class="spinner-border fs-6 text-secqr-orange" role="status">
                                                    <span class="visually-hidden">Saving...</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </ProgressTemplate>
                                    </asp:UpdateProgress>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnProfileDetailsCancel" runat="server" CssClass="bi bi-x-circle-fill fs-3 text-red pe-2" ToolTip="Cancel" CommandName="cancel" CommandArgument="personal" Visible="false"></asp:LinkButton>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnProfileDetailsEdit" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-warning" ToolTip="Edit" CommandName="edit" CommandArgument="personal">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkbtnProfileDetailsCancel" EventName="Click" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkbtnProfileDetailsEdit" EventName="Click" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            
            <!-- More Panels with Other Info Below  -->

        </div>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hidImgSrc" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    </div>
</form>

Code-behind:
Protected Sub btnUploadImage_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnUploadImage.Click
    If filUploadPhoto.HasFile Then
        Dim fi As FileInfo = New FileInfo(filUploadPhoto.FileName)
        Dim strFileName As String = "testing.jpg"
        Dim filePathAndName As String = Server.MapPath("~\img\profile") & "\" & strFileName
        Try
            filUploadPhoto.SaveAs(filePathAndName)
            imgImageToCrop.ImageUrl = "~\img\profile\" & strFileName
            mpe_Crop.Show()
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Failed to Save.
        End Try
    Else
        'No File.
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub lnkbtnCropImage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lnkbtnCropImage.Click
    Dim sbCropperScript As New StringBuilder
    With sbCropperScript
        .Append("setCropper();")
    End With
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "setupCopper", sbCropperScript.ToString, True)
End Sub

enter image description here
enter image description here

Since you using the AJ toolkit, then why not use the asyncFileUpload, or even the AjaxFileUpLoader (they work correctly inside of a UP panel, since they don't require a post-back).
An update panel's very job and existence in life is to NOT post back the whole page, but a file upload control needs a full-page post-back!
So, that rules out using file upload in a UP panel, since you now having to introduce a full-page post-back, and that means the UP can't work with a file upload control. You try and make the File Upload work, then you going to suffer a full-page post back.
So, turns out that using a file Upload in a UP panel does not work, and examples that suggest to fix this are forcing a full-page post back, and thus you already defeated the purpose of the UP panel.
Also, why try and re-size the picture client side, and THEN you want to save the file again server side? That means you still have to re-upload the picture, or at the very least process the image control on a button click.
Thus, once the picture is uploaded, then re-size with code behind, and send that back to the image control. Either way, you’re going to suffer a re-upload of that image, or a re-download of that image, and thus you not gain any speed or increased response and performance here at all.
Keep in mind any page post-back will in most cases collapse the popup extender panel anyway.
Hence, I suggest that you adopt an AJ upload control, and that means no page post-back will occur when you upload. However, in near all cases, you probably attach a client-side post-back JavaScript routine for say the AjaxFileUpLoad control since after uploading the problem actually is no post-back! And such a post-back can be limited to the Update panel.
While I still use the AJ toolkit (for the up-loader, and some masked inputs), I now use a jQuery.UI dialog, since they are more flexible, offer better screen positioning, and you can use them in an update panel.
So, then I suggest re-sizing the image server side, since you wanting to save that re-sized image anyway, right?
If you were re-sizing before the upload, then fine, but looking at the code, the resize is to occur after the upload, and that means we are still uploading the original file along with its original file size.
I suspect there is a way to re-size the image before uploading, but your narrative does not suggest that is the goal here.
So, first step is to remove that File Upload control - it requires a full page post-back to work. (Not even clear how you managed to place and have that File Upload work inside of the Update Panel - it never worked for me in the past due to that control requiring a full-page post-back, but introduction of an update panel thus conflicts with use of that control.
I can post some sample code to upload and re-size, but that would be server-side code to do the re-size.

Thanks Albert, yeah I looked at the AsyncPostback, it's probably the ugliest thing I've seen since the iMac.  I'll do some fishing about & see if I can find some CSS to make it look better. I did monkey around with it some more today & managed to include some extra JavaScript which seems to make it behave better.  Cropper.cs does an awesome job of resizing the image on the client. I was doing the upload immediately because I was losing the cropped image because of the PostBack, but I think I've got that sorted now.  I'll try the AsyncPostback. Thanks for the input, got the gear working again.

Ok, I mean, update panels are great and often allow one to avoid having to write any js code, but uploading is a exception, and for reasons of security, no js code can select a user's file (if one could, then when you come to my site I could steal files from your computer such as files called banking, or your contacts). So, in all cases, the user has to select a file, not js code.  I mean, you could well dump the update panel, and use client side code here.  And it probably should have been made more clear that you are looking to re-size client side.
